# How to write a command in shell script to install GRASS extension?

Tags: grass-7.0, shell

I have a script shell (UBUNTU 14.4) installing an environment for batch processing in PYTHON.
It installs GRASS like this :

```
echo '     installing PYTHON-GDAL    '
echo '-------------------------------'
apt-get install python-gdal
echo '-------------------------------'
echo '     installing GRASS          '
echo '-------------------------------'
apt-get install grass
apt-get install grass-dev
```

Next, how can I code the installation of  GRASS extension (exple : v.centerpoint) in that shell?

Comment: Do you still have that issue?

Comment: No. It's now ok. I used a sh script like this :
GISDBASE=$HOME/grassdata
LOC=install
MAPSET=tmp

myGISRC=$HOME/.grassrc
echo "GISDBASE: $GISDBASE" >  $myGISRC
echo "LOCATION_NAME: $LOC" >> $myGISRC
echo "MAPSET: $MAPSET" >> $myGISRC
export GISRC=$myGISRC
#
export PATH=$PATH:$GISBASE/bin:$GISBASE/scripts
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$GISBASE/lib
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$GISBASE/etc/python
export GIS_LOCK=$$
g.extension extension=v.centerpoint operation=add
GRASS_ADDON_BASE=$HOME/.grass7/addons